# Convert a date into a numer in R

Tags: r, date

The dataset I have has a list of dates, date1 and date2, in the format `yyyymmdd`

`require(date)
 date1: 1960-01-02, 1962-09-30, ...
 date2: 1960-01-15, 1962-09-01,...`

I want to find the numbers of days apart, for example, there are 13 days apart from the first date in date1 to the first date in date2. 
I have tried `as.numeric(as.date(date1,orgin="1960-01-01"))` but I get the error message, "Cannot coerce to date format"

Can someone help me?

Comment: use lubridate library

Comment: Or use base R `as.Date` then `-` (or `difftime`).

Comment: I have tried that. I get the error: Error in as.Date.default(Date1) : 
  do not know how to convert 'Date1' to class “Date”

Comment: `difftime` did the trick, I did that originally, it didn't work the first time, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what Hadley Wickham's `lubridate` library is great at.

```
#install.packages('lubridate')
library(lubridate)
date1 <- c('1960-01-02', '1962-09-30')
date2 <- c('1960-01-15', '1962-09-01')

# "ymd" = "year|month|day"
d1 <- ymd(date1)
d2 <- ymd(date2)
```

Then we can calculate intervals by just subtracting the vectors.

```
> d2-d1
Time differences in days
[1]  13 -29
```

Comment: I installed the package and did what you surgest, but I got the error Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: can't help you much without seeing the error. It would help more if you could provide a minimal example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That means your dates are not in a "year month day" format that lubridate was able to understand. You need to post some sample data.

Comment: I pulled out the list the list of dates I wanted to look at ,                               date1 = c(1965-01-06, 1965-12-16, ...)
date2 = c(1965-01-16, 1966-02-26, ...) this is how my dates are formated

Comment: the full colon notation in your original example is not valid R and therefore not a working example. I created character vectors with those dates in my example and that code runs. Are you experiencing issues running my example locally? Or are you experiencing issues running my suggested solution on your data? Because I only know as much about your data as you tell me, and you aren't giving me much to work with. Help me help you. Give me a minimal working example that includes generating some fake data and results in the error. Otherwise there's not much I can do for you.

Comment: date1 and date2 are in vector form, but they are not character, it is in time